# Add-Migration not picking up changes in the data model code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration

I have created a code first project and started by putting a list of the classes that were required with only their ID, as I have added fields to the table one of the tables does not seem to be having the fields added to the database despite the code being saved and the data library compiled.

I have tried Add-Migration InitialCreate and this does not pick up the new field, is there any file that I can delete that would stop any previous schema from interfering with this? I have the following class:

```
Public Class MeterPointAddress

<Key>
Public Property MeterPointAddressID As Integer

<StringLength(10)>
Public Property UnitNo

<StringLength(40)>
Public Property AddrLine1

<StringLength(40)>
Public Property AddrLine2

<StringLength(10)>
Public Property HouseNo

<StringLength(60)>
Public Property Street

<StringLength(40)>
Public Property AddrLine4

<StringLength(40)>
Public Property AddrLine5

<StringLength(10)>
Public Property PostCode

<StringLength(40)>
Public Property City

<StringLength(3)>
Public Property CountyIreland

<StringLength(3)>
Public Property Country
```

End Class

But when I run the database migrations this table is created with only one field. Please help

Comment: sounds odd, make sure you get and set are both public.  Properties without a public setter won't get added.  That's the only time I've seen columns not getting added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was forgetting to set the type, looked right as I am used to coding in C# dumb mistake had code blindness lol